# Sintaxis. Imprimir var HTML en AJAX, duda

Tags: html, ajax

Ando un poco perdido en `AJAX` y estoy aprendiendo. Tengo un par de dudas concretas y esta es una de ellas.

Si escribo esto:

```
$("#div_Result").html("<p>"+getname+getsurname+"</p>"   );
```

el resultado me da esto:

```
"Name""Surname"
```

Cómo formular la sintaxis para que me evite esas comillas? Muchas gracias

Comment: Las comillas no las estás agregando, ya vienen en el valor de esas variables. Quizás deberías revisar y/o publicar el resto del código para entender dónde se agregan.

Comment: ¿Cómo recuperas ambos valores?

Comment: De una local storage que creo así:

 localStorage.setItem('respuestaServer.getname', JSON.stringify(respuestaServer.getname));  

y recupero así

var getname = localStorage.getItem('respuestaServer.getname');

Comment: @rafa_pe, La pregunta ha de contener toda la informacion relevante para su resolucion. Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir ese codigo, no la pongas en comentarios

Answer (score 2):

Solucionado:

Estaba almacenando las variables en local storage con JSON.stringify y heredaba la caracterísitica.

Manera Incorrecta (en este caso, puede que en otra circunstancia sí sea necesario stringify)

```
    localStorage.setItem('respuestaServer.name', JSON.stringify(respuestaServer.name));
```

Manera correcta

```
    localStorage.setItem('respuestaServer.name', respuestaServer.name);
```

Muchísimas gracias a todos los que habéis respondido.

Comment: Depende de si estás intentando guardar un string o un objeto.. Se puede usar `JSON.stringify(objeto)` y luego de recuperarlo, usar `JSON.parse()`

Comment: correcto, de ahí lo de la otra circunstancia. Muchas gracias.